# How to replace double slash with single slash for an url

Tags: java, regex

For the given url like "http://google.com//view/All/builds", i want to replace the double slash with single slash. For example the above url should display as "http://google.com/view/All/builds"

I dint know regular expressions. Can any one help me, how can i achieve this using regular expressions.

Comment: What did you try ? Do you know Google ?

Comment: You don't need REs. Simple methods on the String class can be used to search for the //, to split the string at that point, and to reassemble a new value without one of the / characters. REs are only needed when searching for more complicated patterns... and they wouldn't change the split-and-reassembly portion of the task.

Comment: except first one all double slashes are to be replaced.

Comment: how are you getting this url in the first place?  it looks to me like it is probably being generated by something...  if so, a better approach might be to tweak your generator so as not to produce the double slash

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To avoid replacing the first // in `http://` use the following regex :

```
String to = from.replaceAll("(?<!http:)//", "/");
```

PS: if you want to handle https use `(?<!(http:|https:))//` instead.

Comment: Replacing any number of slashes: ```.replaceAll("(?<!(http:|https:))/+", "/");```

Answer (score 22):

## Is Regex the right approach?

In case you wanted this solution as part of an exercise to improve your regex skills, then fine. But what is it that you're really trying to achieve? You're probably trying to normalize a URL. Replacing `//` with `/` is one aspect of normalizing a URL. But what about other aspects, like removing redundant `./` and collapsing `../` with their parent directories? What about different protocols? What about `///`? What about the `//` at the start? What about `///` at the start in case of `file:///`?

If you want to write a generic, reusable piece of code, using a regular expression is probably not the best appraoch. And it's reinventing the wheel. Instead, consider `java.net.URI.normalize()`.

## `java.net.URI.normalize()`

### `java.lang.String`

```java
String inputUrl = "http://localhost:1234//foo//bar//buzz";
String normalizedUrl = new URI(inputUrl).normalize().toString();
```

### `java.net.URL`

```java
URL inputUrl = new URL("http://localhost:1234//foo//bar//buzz");
URL normalizedUrl = inputUrl.toURI().normalize().toURL();
```

### `java.net.URI`

```java
URI inputUri = new URI("http://localhost:1234//foo//bar//buzz");
URI normalizedUri = inputUri.normalize();
```

## Regex

In case you *do* want to use a regular expression, think of all possibilities. What if, in future, this should also process other protocols, like `https`, `file`, `ftp`, `fish`, and so on? So, think again, and probably use `URI.normalize()`. But if you insist on a regular expression, maybe use this one:

```
String noramlizedUri = uri.replaceAll("(?<!\\w+:/?)//+", "/");
```

Compared to other solutions, this works with all URLs that look similar to HTTP URLs just with different protocols instead of `http`, like `https`, `file`, `ftp` and so on, and it will keep the triple-slash `///` in case of `file:///`. But, unlike `java.net.URI.normalize()`, this does not remove redundant `./`, it does not collapse `../` with their parent directories, it does not other aspects of URL normalization that you and I might have forgotten about, and it will not be updated automatically with newer RFCs about URLs, URIs, and such.

Comment: Note that the `java.net.URI` constructor throws a checked exception. Use convenience static factory method `java.net.URI.create` instead for strings you know are valid.

Answer (score 4):

```
String to = from.replaceAll("(?<!(http:|https:))[//]+", "/");
```

will match two or more slashes.

Comment: Doesn [//]+ only match even numbers of slashes?

Comment: As @fall said, it replaces only an even number of slashes. `foo////bar` would become `foo/bar` but `foo///bar` would become `foo//bar`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the regexp:

`/(?<=[^:\s])(\/+\/)/g`

It finds multiple slashes in url preserving ones after protocol regardless of it.
Handles also protocol relative urls which start from `//`.

```
@Test
public void shouldReplaceMultipleSlashes() {
    assertEquals("http://google.com/?q=hi", replaceMultipleSlashes("http://google.com///?q=hi"));
    assertEquals("https://google.com/?q=hi", replaceMultipleSlashes("https:////google.com//?q=hi"));
    assertEquals("//somecdn.com/foo/", replaceMultipleSlashes("//somecdn.com/foo///"));
}

private static String replaceMultipleSlashes(String url) {
      return url.replaceAll("(?<=[^:\\s])(\\/+\\/)", "/");
}
```

Literally means:

- `(\/+\/)` - find group: `/+` one or more slashes followed by `/` slash
- `(?<=[^:\s])` - which follows the group *(*posiive lookbehind)* of this *(*negated set)* `[^:\s]` that excludes `:` colon and `\s` whitespace
- `g` - global search flag

Comment: Surly the escape on the forward slashes is redundant? i.e. `(?<=[^:\s])(/+/)`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you simply use String.replace which documentation is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Something like 
`myString.replace("//", "/");

If you want to remove the first occurence:

`String[] parts = str.split("//", 2);
str = parts[0] + "//" + parts[1].replaceAll("//", "/");`

Which is the simplest way (without regular expression). I don't know the regular expression corresponding, if there is an expert looking at the thread.... ;)

Comment: this will replace all double slash to single. but my requirement is except for the first occurance it should replace for all double slash

Comment: might it be better to include the : in the split instead of specifying 2?  I believe str.split("//",2) when used on the asker's example will return the array ["http:", "google.com/"] but I could be wrong...

Comment: 'split' allows us to separate in only two parts, which prevent from using a 'for' loop afterwards on parts[]. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)