# Disallow multiple slashes in a URL in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, url

Is there any configuration in Spring Boot to make multiple slashes in a url unreachable?

Or how to make controller methods handle only correct path values?

Example (such requests should not be handled):

`/api/v1/hello//world`

`/api/v1/hello/../hello/world`

Comment: I think you have to gonna through regex expression to check the url. See here for further explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173575/how-to-replace-double-slash-with-single-slash-for-an-url

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej, thanks for your comment. I’ve already solved the problem using URI#normalize method. But I'm still wondering if there is a ready solution in SpringBoot